# 5.7 Hemi Failure Modes?

Tags: chrysler-300c

We own a 2008 Chrysler 300c that has now done 220,000 Km .Most of the driving was UBER .The engine has now died .It had to be pushed into the garage .There was a lot of white smoke .A mechanic reckons that it smells like a cooked motor .I tried to restart the engine and it was difficult needing much more throttle than normal .There was a very loud rattle and the engine warning lamp was on .I turned off immediatly .The car had always been serviced .We did note some oil usage but no apparent leaks on the garage floor and no blowby or blue smoke .Was oil finding its way into the water ? Could this be a head gasket fail ? Could the rattle be valves ?Do I need a Crate motor to escape this Automotive Armageddon?

Comment: What are the codes?

Comment: The mechanic pulled the motor informing us of a broken heater hose so it cooked .When I tried to start it the engine lamp came on .We have purchased a crate motor .

Comment: Ouch ... Hemi's aren't cheap. From your description, sounds about like the right diagnosis. Either a crate engine or get a rebuild, but considering you have 220kkm on it, you've mostly gotten your money's worth.